# How to fix MariaDB InnoDB "Data structure corruption" after using plesk system reboot

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, plesk, data-recovery

I logged into the server using SSH and it said my server needed to have a reboot. So I logged into my plesk panel and hit the restart server button. After the reboot... MySQL/MariaDB doesn't start anymore. I'm getting errors that seem to indicate database corruption. I would really appreciate some advice on how to fix this issue. I don't encounter this problem very often.

Some sites have said to reinstall the database. Other places have said to use innodb_force_recovery. I do not have any backups (I know, Shame on me. This is a personal server.). I DO have a copy of the /var/lib/mysql directory. Though the copy is taken AFTER the database stopped booting.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04LTS

```
"journal -xe" outputs this info:
 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man pa>
 [ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4000 in ./ibdata1
 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr 16 12:45:41 mysite.com named[1988]: client @0x7feec0011480 1.2.3.4#68 (sl): query (cache) 'sl/ANY/IN' denied
 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr 16 12:45:41 mysite.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Apr 16 12:45:41 mysite.com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 12:45:41 mysite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 9726 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: This looks like you previously had MySQL installed, and then mariadb got installed. Uninstall MariaDB and install your previous MySQL version.

Comment: You are exactly correct. You can also install and run a docker image that uses mysql 8, then mount your /var/lib/mysql folder in the docker image so it points towards your copy of your actual server's /var/lib/mysql folder. That allows you to then access your database using docker, at which point you can make a mysql data dump file. And... well, you'll still have to remake all your user accounts. Oh well.

Comment: "Uninstall MariaDB and install previous Mysql". Sounds so easy. Good luck with that. Once maria has a poke at the tables/config on Ubuntu at least it quickly turns into a nightmare.